# How do you change(make it larger) the size of an icon inside a GRID in reactjs/material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I already had the size of the icon I wanted but after enclosing this icon in `<Grid item> </Grid>` the size of the icon became smaller. I want the size to be as almost as big as the `Grid` container.

If you could help me I will appreciate it; I have googled my question but I have not been able to find an answer; thanks.

Here is the code:

```
 <Grid container className={classes.bannerRoot}>
   <Grid item>
     <InboxIcon style={{ fontsize: 200 }} /> 
   </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

where `bannerRoot` is:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(6),
  },
  bannerRoot: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
    minHeight: '225px',
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(3),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have a spelling mistake on fontSize:

```
export function OpenDialogue() {
const classes = useStyles();
return (
    <Grid container className={classes.bannerRoot}>
        <Grid item>
            <LaunchIcon style={{ fontSize: 200 }} />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
)
```

}

Comment: yeah, I have just noticed that.